# Is it ok to work for spotify Islamically?

Tags: halal-haram, music

I would like to know if it is okay to work for spotify as iOS application developer. Be it an app which involves music directly or indirectly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not halal because you are helping or working with a Music-Oriented Company. As Music is haram in Islam

**Allah says in **[Luqman 31:6] :****

> “And of mankind is he who
> purchases idle talks
> (i.e. music, singing) to
> mislead (men) from the
> path of Allah…”

*The scholar of the ummah,
Ibn 'Abbas (may Allah be pleased with him) said: this means singing .
Mujahid (may Allah have mercy on him) said: this means playing the drum (tabl).
(Tafsir al-Tabari, 21/40)*

*Al-Hasan al-Basri (may Allah have mercy on him) said:
this ayah was revealed concerning singing and
musical instruments (lit. woodwind instruments). (Tafsir Ibn Kathir, 3/451)*

**And According to Hadith :**

> “Among my ummah there will
> certainly be people
> who permit zina,
> silk, alcohol
> and musical instruments…”

***So It is clear that Music/Singing/instruments are haram.***

Working In Spotify is also haram because you are helping in spread of what is haram:

Referring to Quran [5:2]:

> ```
> And cooperate in righteousness 
> and piety, but do not cooperate 
>  in sin and aggression. And 
> fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is 
>  severe in penalty.
> ```

**This indicates that we should not work cooperate in sinful activities.**

***Also what do you mean by working Islamic-ally if its adding qur'anic recitation or bayan then its ok to earn from that.***

Thanks to [Is Music Haram?](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5000/is-music-haram) and legacy.quran.com for references and sources.

Comment: reference for hadith : (Narrated by al-Bukhari ta’liqan, no. 5590; narrated as mawsul by al-Tabarani and al-Bayhaqi. See al-Silsilah al-Sahihah by al-Albani, 91)