# Is me promoting a company in the music industry haram

Tags: halal-haram

I am an email marketer freelancer by profession, I use email channels to promote products and services.

For some time I've been promoting a company's software that allows people to learn drums and today I started promoting their DRUM kit, I didn't realize that I was promoting a product/service from the music industry until today when I was writing email content for the drum kit.

I want to know if what I have been doing is haram and if yes then what should I do with the money I earned from it.

I have always been steadfast in avoiding companies that are in the haram industry, I've been approached by several clients in the haram industry, and I always outright rejected them but this time I didn't realize it until today.

Can anyone please tell me if what am doing is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question [Working for Spotify Islamically](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76626/is-it-ok-to-work-for-spotify-islamically/76627#76627) and see [what to do with Haram money](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/78289)

Answer (score 1):

Promotion of Haram is Haram as you are a helping hand for spreading Haram things.

Reffering to [5:2]:

> Cooperate with one another in goodness and righteousness, and do not cooperate in sin and transgression. And be mindful of Allah. Surely Allah is severe in punishment.

**[5:2](https://quran.com/al-maidah/2)** clearly states that we should not cooperate in sin. So promotion of drums, piano etc is Haram .

If you have made some money from promotion of Haram you should check [what to do with Haram money?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/78289) to better know what to do with that Haram money.

These type of questions have been asked previously so  check them aswell.